# WPF *.rdlc Report Deploy

Tags: wpf

Good morning, i have make wpf application on visual studio 2010, this have 5 rdlc file report,
when i try to start it on machine with VisualStudio (win7 and win8), no have problem, but if i try to start it in machine clean i dont see the rdlc report.

I try to install ReportView of Visual Studio 2010,
 but the result is the same and i try to install ReportView of 2012, 
but it not have Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012 Feature Pack.. but i not find it on microsoft downloads.

Is there a way to see the report on clear win8 machine??